# Why is a web_accessible_resource able to access other non - web_accessible_resource in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I have a chrome MV3 extension that I am developing locally.
Now I have a content script that injects an iframe into a  user site.
The iframe's html src is a `sample.html` file whose url we get using `chrome.runtime.getURL('/iframeinjector/sample.html'))`.
Now this file links a `sample.css` & a `sample.js` as well.

When I declare the iframe.html as web_accessible_resource I am able to import css & js files as well without those files being in web_acesssible_resources.

Expectedly I cant access iframe.html if I dont declare it in web_accessible_resources. so then why am i able to access css/js files without them being declared as web_accessible_resource .

**manifest.json**

```
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
{
    "resources": [
        "/iframeinjector/sample.html",
    ],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "extension_ids": ["extension_id1234"]
}]
...
```

**contentScript.js**

```
$injectedIframe.setAttribute('id', 'extension-iframe');
$injectedIframe.setAttribute('src', chrome.runtime.getURL('/injectediframe/sample.html'));
```

**sample.html(iframe src)**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/built.min.css"></link>
  </head>
  <body >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dist that I am uploading to chrome contains those js & css files.
Given the definition of web_accessible_resource I would not expect a resource to be available at all if its not listed as such.

Comment: Because the iframe is a different document with a `chrome-extension://id/` URL, so it has access to everything within this path, i.e. all of the extension's resources.